# How do I make a raw HTTP request in Java?

Tags: java, http

I want to make a basic HTTP request using these tokens: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

I know Java does it for you normally, but I want to specifically set certain tokens.

Comment: You may want to look at this question/answer [session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021392/java-web-app-security-adding-tokens-to-requests)

Comment: You can first remove the "in Java" in your question. Then you will ask "how to open a socket in Java" and here you're gonna have your answer.

Comment: I don't see the motivation for this question. You can 'specifically set certain tokens' via java.net.HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel ? The Apache Http Client 4 [conforms to rfc2616](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/).

Comment: Definitely use this, and it does allow you to "set certain tokens"

If not, this is an OOP language. Override a method.

Answer (score 1):

Open a socket to port 80 on the host you want to connect to, and then just write to the stream in the same way you'd write to a file or the console.