# Fetch data from other Website

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a raw HTTP request in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264562/how-do-i-make-a-raw-http-request-in-java)

I am monitoring a website which updates transaction data every few seconds, so for having better performance I need to store those data and analyze them (like plotting, etc.).

My question is how I can make a request to that server by Java EE and get the values which are available in a table in that site?

I should add that I do not search a solution by .net or php, and I have tried by JQuery, java HTTPRequest but I did not found the solution.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If they provide some sort of API/webservice that is best way to communicate,

if not and if the source site doesn't have any issue with the data you are taking from them you could use HTTP requests to get HTML response and parse the portion you want using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org)

Comment: Thanks, I knew ba JSoup we can get the source code but actually I am searching for the values in the table, for example how I can get a data from following line? <td id="BV2"> </td>

Comment: check jsoup api doc, there is a method to fetch HTML dom by id

Comment: Actually the problem is, by javascript the data will be updated, but Jsoup does not see that

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried anything yourself yet? SO is not a code generation tool.

That being said, this seems to be of interest: [How do I make a raw HTTP request in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264562/how-do-i-make-a-raw-http-request-in-java)

Comment: It is not the same question, by a simply HTTP request I get timeout error from that site.

Comment: I still stand by my main comment that SO is not a code generation tool. You've not provided any evidence that you have even tried anything yourself yet.

The HTTP request in Java question seemed relevant, hence the link. I didn't say it was the same question, just that it might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, but it is much better to check the question and the answer of this question and related questions before leaving any comment